# Confirmation message not getting rendered when printing the elements seprately in twig and ajax is enabled

Tags: 8, ajax, webforms

Iam using the following twig code in webform-submission-form--newsletter-signup.html.twig

```
                        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                            {{ form.elements.url }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                                {{ form.elements.email }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 mt-3 text-center">
                         {{ form.elements.actions }}
                        </div>

                    {{ form.form_build_id }}
      {{ form.form_token }}
      {{ form.form_id }}
```

and Iam using the following code in webform--newsletter-signup.html.twig

```
 <form{{ attributes.addClass('subscribe-form') }}>
  <div class="row">

  {{ title_prefix }}
  {{ children }}
  {{ title_suffix }}
  </div>

</form>
```

When I try to use the default webform templates the message gets displayed after ajax request infact the message is returned as part of the data in response but when I use these templates the message is not present in ajax response what am I doing wrong here please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to still include `{{ title_prefix }}` and  `{{ title_suffix }}` in your template

In the comments in the default webform.html.twig it gives a short description of the default variables "Additional output populated by modules" which includes essentially anything else apart from the form elements themselves

Comment: These two variables already form the part of my webform--newsletter-signup.html.twig file but message is not rendered